# Add custom icon

Tags: flutter, convex-bottom-bar

Hi i am using the library :
convex_bottom_bar to create my bottom bar

```
    StyleProvider(
  style: Style(),
  child: ConvexAppBar(
    initialActiveIndex: 1,
    height: 50,
    top: -30,
    curveSize: 100,
    style: TabStyle.fixedCircle,
    items: [
      TabItem(icon: Icons.link),
      TabItem(icon: Icons.import_contacts),
      TabItem(title: "2020", icon: Icons.work),
    ],
    backgroundColor: _tabBackgroundColor,
  ),
)
```

However, i want to change the icon and add my custom icon, i try this but it doesn' t work:

> icon: index==1?new Image.asset('images/1.0x/icon2.png'):new
> Image.asset('images/1.0x/newIcon.png'),

Any idea how to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here you could either use some kind of font file for your icons which might in general be the better way because of various reasons such as app size and image scaling issues or you could use image files such as .png or .svg. You should have that in mind.

Looking at your code snippet it looks like you want to use image files.
In convex-bottom-bar tab items are generic type since version 1.3.1 so both `IconData` and `Widget` can be used (see [1.3.1](https://pub.dev/packages/convex_bottom_bar/changelog)).

That means something like the following is possible:

```
TabItem(
        icon: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Color(0xFFFF5722),
      ),
      child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white, size: 40),
    )),
```

See this [example](https://github.com/hacktons/convex_bottom_bar/blob/master/example/lib/custom_appbar_sample.dart) example for more information.

So just replace the `IconData` with your Image widget and it should work.